# how do I access a variable at a certain position in Python

Tags: python

I'm writing a program in python that is supposed to print out a list in ascending order.

the ouput should look like this

```
element 0 is apple
element 1 is pear
```

etc..

I'm having trouble grabbing the variable stored in a particular position and was wondering if I did the syntax wrong.

here is the code:

```
def print_elements(listvar):
    """prints a list out one element at a time"""
    count = 0
    count2 =0 
    while listvar[count] != None:
        print("Element " + count + "is ", listvar[::count2])
        count = count +1
        count2 = count +1

print_elements(["Apple", "Cherry", "Banana"])
print_elements(["Walnut", "Pecan", "Peanut", "Cashew"])
print_elements(["Rajinder", "Eva", "Patel", "Thao", "Greta"])
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a straight forward case for `enumerate` and a `for` loop

```
def print_elements(listvar):
    for index, value in enumerate(listvar):
        print('element {} is {}'.format(index, value))
```

Example

```
>>> print_elements(["Apple", "Cherry", "Banana"])
element 0 is Apple
element 1 is Cherry
element 2 is Banana
```

Also, you should not do

```
while listvar[count] != None:
```

Because you are assuming that when you index past the end of the list, you will get `None`, that is not correct, it will return an error if you index out of range.

If you really wanted to use a `while` loop, you would change the condition to

```
while count < len(listvar):
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this solved my problems.  We haven't covered enumeration yet but this did the trick.

Comment: @snew929 - If you havent covered `enumerate`, look into how python list index works. Although `enumerate` is the straight forward and pythonic way to go. May be your  professor wanted you to dive into indexes for this problem